# Universal property of polynomial ring in $\mathbf{CRING}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I know that the polynomial ring $A[x]$ is the free $A$-algebra on $\{x\}$; this is its universal property in the category of $A$-algebras. Is there also a universal property for $A[x]$ considered as a ring, which uniquely determines $A[x]$ in $\mathbf{CRING}$? Would be very useful, as I grew up in $\mathbf{CRING}$!

Comment: It is the coproduct (or tensor product, if you like) of $A$ and $\mathbb{Z} [x]$, where $\mathbb{Z} [x]$ is the free ring on one generator.

Comment: @ZhenLin: thank you very much! somehow this escaped my notice. Please post your comment as an answer, for it fully resolves the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The polynomial ring $A [x]$ is the coproduct of $A$ and $\mathbb{Z} [x]$.

One way to see this is to note that the category of (commutative unital) $A$-algebras is isomorphic to the slice category $^{A /} \mathbf{CRing}$, and the forgetful functor $^{A /} \mathbf{CRing} \to \mathbf{CRing}$ has a left adjoint, namely $B \mapsto A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$. Since adjoints compose, we deduce that the free $A$-algebra on one generator is the coproduct of $A$ and the free commutative ring on one generator.

Comment: In other words, $\hom(A[x],B) \cong \hom(A,B) \times |B|$, where $|B|$ is the underlying set of $B$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I have seen your comment somewhere else, and I could not infer from it that $A[x]=A\coprod\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but I now understand it. By the way is it correct that $\mathrm{Hom}(A_f,B)=\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)\times|B^\ast|=\mathrm{Hom}(A[x]/(xf-1),B)$? I could thus conclude $A_f=A[x]/(xf-1)$. (I learned this method of proof from one of your posts!)